# How do i hide file path information in VS-Code Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see this unnecessary file path information whenever I execute a program in the terminal section.
Is there a way to hide that file path?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much VSCode *terminal* related, rather it is more *shell* related (see [What's the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506510/what-is-the-difference-between-terminal-console-shell-and-command-line)). Your VScode's terminal is running a shell internally, but a terminal is not much more than a display window that calls a shell's functions. So, in order to edit the prompt (which comes from the shell), we have to edit your shell config.

From your screenshot, it looks like the particular shell you're running is Powershell. Powershell has its own prompt that it generates each time before you run a command. It does so by calling the `prompt()` function (you can read more about it at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1)).

Therefore, if you just want an **empty prompt**, then all you have to do is create an **empty prompt function** and add it to your power*shell* profile.

From your terminal, open your powershell profile file using VSCode (or any text editor)

```sh
# $profile is a variable in powershell 
# that holds path of the powershell config
code $profile
```

Then add an empty prompt function into the profile

```
function prompt { }
```

Save the file and reopen another powershell instance in your VSCode terminal, and now it should look like this

```
PS>
```

If you're interested in further customizing this prompt, I would highly recommend looking into [starship](https://starship.rs/), a cross-platform shell prompt that can be used inside powershell. By default it's an even simpler arrow

```
❯
```

It only displays the most relevant paths, and can be customized to a much greater extent than the powershell prompt.